# Getting data from phpmyadmin and transfer each item to a textview in eclipse

Tags: android, mysql, eclipse, select

in need of help on this kind of matter,i just wanted some tips and thoughts about it..

example:
i have a table named listOfPeople and inside are the following:
-idnum
-name
-age
-location

then in eclipse,
i have **4 textviews** and **1 button**,
then, if i pressed the button, the NAME,AGE and LOCATION will show in the 3 textviews with a specific idnum

Persons ID Number : **1**
Name of person : **sample sample**
Age of person : **14**
Persons location : **sample area**

what should i do? i have a jsonParser running up, a defaulthttpclient, xampp as my connector and phpmyadmin as my database.

in my php code (select.php) :
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listOfPeople WHERE idnum='$idnum'");

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/   This might help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect to a mysql database from an Android device directly. You have to run a web service on your server which fetches the data from the database (I see you already have a php script so I suggest using that one) and convert that to JSON and send that back to your Android device.
In your app you can parse the incoming JSON to separate strings and set these strings to the appropriate `TextView`s using `setText(string)`

Comment: i have an AsyncTask running and also this  >>>      
         
   protected String doInBackground(String...args) {   
   List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

Comment: I would do the JSON parsing there and give the `List` to a custom adapter (extending) `BaseAdapter` and pass that adapter to a `ListView`

Comment: String name = nametextview.setText(); <<<< having errors

Comment: The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments () <<<< my error

Comment: Because you can't you `setText(CharSequence)` like that. You have to use it like this `nametextview.setText(name)`.